# Назначать несколько CSS классов тексту - правильный подход?

Tags: html, css, frontend, sass, scss

В мобильном приложении, над которым я работаю, есть много разных элементов, с текстом разного размера, цвета и шрифта. Вместо того чтобы создавать CSS класс для каждого типа текстового элемента (например .text-green-small-bold), я собираюсь создать несколько классов для параметров текста и назначать 2 или более классов одному текстовому элементу (.text-green .text-bold. text-small). Мне кажется так можно избежать путаницы, накопления кучи классов и несогласованности в дизайне.

Мой вопрос: это правильный подход, или есть другие лучшие принятые практики?
Спасибо!

Comment: если это только оправданно ...хотя удобно ..можно один и тот же класс использовать кучу раз ...

Comment: Если такое разнообразие используется в КОНТЕНТЕ (то бишь управляется через админку), то можно. Не забудьте только перенести/сказать прогерам чтобы перенесли ваши классы в текстовый редактор.

Comment: А в чем проблемма? Так и делают вроде как